# Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, 0.525923 ACPI proble failed

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot

I have installed ubuntu more than 3 times and the problem is not yet solved.
My pc is dual boot with windows7. Graphics card is nvidia gtx780 and the processor is an intel i7.

After the first installation of ubuntu, i did a full update using the software updater followed by a system restart. Then after choosing ubuntu in grub menu i get a: The system is running in low graphics mode. One more restart to go the grub menu and from there i chose the option of recovery mode which did not do anything.

Again a fresh installation of ubuntu. This time i thought it was the drivers of graphics card so i installed them using sudo apt-get nvidia current, followed this guide ([How to fix "The system is running in low-graphics mode" error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)). I restarted and i got the system is running in low graphics mode.

Again a new installation of ubuntu. This time i only installed numlockx from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install numlockx
sudo sed -i 's|^exit 0.*$|# Numlock enable\n[ -x /usr/bin/numlockx ] \&\& numlockx on\n\nexit 0|' /etc/rc.local
gksudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
greeter-setup-script=/usr/bin/numlockx on
```

After a couple of restarts once again i got the error system is running in low graphics. So i opened the terminal and pressed

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

and then a restart. After choosing ubuntu i get the error:

```
0.525923 ACPI proble failed
```

and i cant do anything.

I am really getting annoyed, what is happening ? Should i install ubuntu again? They have broken up 3 times already. I had never a problem like this using virtual box on windows. Any help ?

Edit*** I found a solution. After searching for some time, i saw a post that ubuntu installation should be done in the following way: choose try ubuntu and then from the dekstop click the install ubuntu icon. It worked like a charm. The strange thing is that using this method the software updater had only 100mb update instead of 300(without using try ubuntu first)..

Comment: You need to install Nvidia drivers.

Answer (score 0):

You installed a wrong driver. Press Ctrl+Alt+F1, login to console and run there:

```
sudo apt-get purge 'nvidia.*'
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Isnt the same with sudo apt-get install nvidia-current ?  I found an older post that states that the install should be done by the option test ubuntu(and then you click the icon) rather than just follow the installer. The crazy thing is that it worked. When i did a software update it was only 100mb rather than 300 (which i got from the other installation method)

Comment: It is not the same. `nvidia-current` installs a legacy driver that does not support your adapter.